# Changing the address value of a function pointer

Tags: c, arm, function-pointers, memory-address, thumb

I have the following code in C:

```
int addInt(int n, int m) {
    return n + m;
}

int (*functionPtr)(int, int);

functionPtr = &addInt;
```

*functionPtr* is a function pointer and it points to the specific address of the function *addInt*. I want to change 1 bit of its value, but I can't figure it out how.

Let's say *functionPtr* points to *0xABC0* (assuming a 16-bit address) after the last statement. I want to change its value to *0xABC1*. I tried to OR the value with 0x1, but I guess that something is wrong with the operand conversion:

```
functionPtr = &addInt | 0x00000001; // addresses are of 32 bits
```

I know that messing around with pointers is risky, but I have to change the LSB of the address in order to enter into the Thumb state of an ARM Cortex-M4 MCU.

Comment: Show your attempts. You need the bit or operator.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do??? Fiddling with function pointers will not get you anywhere.

Comment: @SergeyA I have to change the LSB of the function pointer so I can enter into the Thumb mode (of an ARM Cortex-M4 MCU).

Comment: @PierpaoloBagnasco: **DO NOT!** Just compile for AAPCS ABI, the compiler will care about this! Messing around with function pointer is nonsense (at least here). This is an XY-problem. Tell us **why** you think you need this. (calling thumb mode is definitively **not**, because Cortex-M4 is Trumb2-only, so you do not even have ARM-code.

Comment: Is this platform LSB?

Comment: @Olaf I know I can use the help of the compiler, but I'd like to do it myself (if there is a way) in order to learn better (and without involving any assembly).

Comment: Cortex-M4 does not have ARM state at all (thus does not even execute ARM code), so you are **always** in Thumb mode. Furtehr more, the compiler will care about this. Why **exactly** do you think you need this?

Comment: So you want to learn how to exploit undefined behaviour? Good grief!

Comment: @user4419802: "Is this platform LSB?": Depends.

Comment: Having just compiled and disassembled the first code snippet (with the assignment wrapped in a function) out of curiosity, it generates (as I expected) perfectly correct code: the address of the function has bit 0 set, _because it is a Thumb function_, and the linker is not incredibly stupid. How did you reach the conclusion you need to go bit-twiddling manually?

Comment: The cortex-M4 only supports **Thumb** mode.  You never need to switch modes on that CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify the value of a pointer via arithmetic operations, you would need to convert it to an integer type, perform the operation, and then convert it back.  C does not define behavior for converting a function pointer to anything other than another function pointer, however, so there is no defined way to do that.

You might nevertheless write this:

```
typedef int (*fptr)(int, int);

functionPtr = (fptr)(((intptr_t) functionPtr) | 1);
```

The behavior you are looking for is one of the more plausible results, but again, the behavior of both casts is *undefined*.  Therefore the behavior to be expected from performing a function call via the modified pointer -- if your program can even get that far -- is also undefined.  The compiler is not required even to accept the code.

Answer (score 1):

Many mentioned that your approach is dangerous, but in some cases, this is a real issue, which I met more than once. I suspect that at the moment your code uses the `BL` instruction (branch and link) which does not change the mode of the CPU to thumb, in order to perform a call from ARM to thumb based on your function pointer, add the [`-mthumb-interwork`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) flag to gcc when compiling your code:

> Generate code that supports calling between the ARM and Thumb
>   instruction sets. Without this option, on pre-v5 architectures, the
>   two instruction sets cannot be reliably used inside one program. The
>   default is -mno-thumb-interwork, since slightly larger code is
>   generated when -mthumb-interwork is specified. In AAPCS configurations
>   this option is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it's a bad idea, but if you really need this, the following can do the trick:

```
functionPtr = &addInt;
*(int*)&functionPtr |= 1;
```

But note that this is no way portable, and may work or no work at all in your environment.

Comment: You cannot cast a function pointer safely to an object pointer. Even worse, it is nonsense for whatever OP wants.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't say it's safe. But it _could_ work sometimes/somewhere.

Comment: Yes, and I could fly sometime/someday (mostly towards the next mass). It is undefined behaviour. Even more, there is no reason to do so here.

Answer (score -2):

The function pointer format is architecture and implementation dependent.

For example, on Itanium, [function pointers point to a read only data structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/07/31/10631975.aspx) containing the appropriate *global pointer* for the module the function belongs to, and the actual function pointer.

Comment: This better was a comment.