# UsageFault when branching to a function pointer on Cortex-M0

Tags: pointers, gcc, arm, cortex-m, thumb

I'm running code on an STM32F0 (ARM Cortex-M0). I define a function pointer to a [nested function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html):

```
void My_Async_Func(void *handle, void (*complete)(bool success)) {
    /* 
     *  \/ A nested function \/
     */
    void receiveHandler(void) {
        // This function lies at an even-numbered address
    }
    /* ... */
    uart->rxDoneHandler = &receiveHandler;
    Go(uart);
}
```

The nested function appears to be screwing things up. Later when I call that `rxDoneHandler` pointer, it tries to branch to `0x8c0c6c0c` and I get a UsageFault. According to the [ARM docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka12544.html), this is because I'm branching to an *even-numbered* address on a processor that only supports the Thumb instruction set, which requires you to only branch to *odd-numbered* addresses.

I'm using GCC arm-none-eabi 4.9.3. My CFLAGS are:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -MMD -MP
```

#### Things I tried

I tried calling gcc with `-mthumb-interwork` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32976472/1161906). Same result.

I tried manually setting the alignment of the function with an attribute like

```
__attribute__((aligned(16))) void receiveHandler(void) {

}
```

Same result.

I tried manually adding 1 to the pointer when I call it like

```
(uart->rxDoneHandler + 1)();
```

Same result.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested function **must** not be called from the outside of the enclosing function unless you're still "logically" inside that function; from the GCC page on nested functions (emphasis mine):

> It is possible to call the nested function from outside the scope of its name by storing its address or passing the address to another function:
>
> ```
>  hack (int *array, int size)
>  {
>    void store (int index, int value)
>      { array[index] = value; }
>
>    intermediate (store, size);
>  }
> ```
>
> Here, the function intermediate receives the address of store as an argument. If intermediate calls store, the arguments given to store are used to store into array. **But this technique works only so long as the containing function (hack, in this example) does not exit.**

My guess is that you register `uart->rxDoneHandler` as a Interrupt Service Routine (or something that is called from within an ISR). You can't do that.

Comment: Huh. Yeah, you're right. Adding a `WFI` instruction to the end of `My_Async_Func` caused it to work, presumably by preventing the function from returning.

Comment: You **still** shouldn't use nested functions from different scopes within an ISR. I can't really imagine this being something that the compiler designers ever considered usage that they should support

Comment: Why does it matter that it's an ISR?

Comment: because it's a "sideways" way to get into the the function. You're not really in the same stack hierarchy.